# WPF ListView item's Visible/Collaped not changing according to its Visibility

Tags: wpf, listview, user-interface, binding, visibility

Thanks for your time reading my thread.

I am using VS2012, WFP, and .net4.5 on Windows 7 64bit

I have a ListView control with xaml in following:

```
<ListView Name="lvViewerControl"
                      SelectionMode="Single"
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=ViewType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      Background="{x:Null}"
                      BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                      Margin="2">
                <Label Name="lblView2D"
                       Width="40"
                       Height="40"
                       Margin="3"
                       Background="#FF595959"
                       Foreground="White"
                       HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                    <Image Source="/CaptureSetupModule;component/Icons/2D.png" />
                </Label>
                <Label Name="lblView3D"
                       Width="40"
                       Height="40"
                       Margin="3"
                       Background="#FF595959"
                       Foreground="White"
                       HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                    <Image Source="/CaptureSetupModule;component/Icons/3D.png" />
                </Label>
                <Label Name="lblViewTiles"                       
                       Width="40"
                       Height="40"
                       Margin="3"
                       Background="#FF595959"
                       Foreground="White"
                       HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                       Visibility="{Binding Path=XYCtrlVisible, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}}">
                    <Image Source="/CaptureSetupModule;component/Icons/Tile.png" />
                </Label>
            </ListView>
```

Now I want to collapse the third item, `lblViewTiles`. I tried to combine its `Visibility` to a bool, then do the bool to visibility conversion, but it did not work. What I mean by not work is that the `Visiblity` only collapses when the application starts (the application loads the xml to get the Visibility as it starts). Afterwards, not matter how the binding variable (`Visiblity`) changes,  and the value does change to `Collapsed`, but the `lblViewTiles` still in the `ListView` control, no UI change.

Here is how  DataContext are binded:
The `DataContex` of the ListView is binded to `CaptureSetupModules` class. The ListView is defined in `LiveVM` class. The action which is the loading of the xml is in `MasterView` class. So in order to access the `Visibility` property in `CaptureSetupModules`, I simply created a `CaptureSetupModules` object  in `MasterView` class,

In MasterView class

```
    CaptureSetupModules _captureVM = new CaptureSetupModules();
    ...

LiveVM _liveVM = new LiveVM;
      if (ndList.Count > 0)
                {
                    xyBorder.Visibility = ndList[0].Attributes["Visibility"].Value.Equals("Visible") ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
                    tilesControlBorder.Visibility = ndList[0].Attributes["Visibility"].Value.Equals("Visible") ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;               
                    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                       new Action(
                           delegate()
                           {

                               _captureVM.XYCtrlVisible = ndList[0].Attributes["Visibility"].Value.Equals("Visible") ? true:false;

                           }
                       )
                   );               
                }
```

And here is my converter:

```
public sealed class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var flag = false;
            if (value is bool)
            {
                flag = (bool)value;
            }
            else if (value is bool?)
            {
                var nullable = (bool?)value;
                flag = nullable.GetValueOrDefault();
            }
            if (parameter != null)
            {
                if (bool.Parse((string)parameter))
                {
                    flag = !flag;
                }
            }
            if (flag)
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
```

This code only makes the item collapsed the first time when the application starts , and it loads the visibility from the xml file. Afterwards, not matter how the `XYCtrlVisible`, the visibility binding, changes, the UI show no response. The item is always there, or not there.

Basically the problem is: the binded variable changes, the xml file changes as well, but the UI does not change, exception for the first time when the application launches as it loads the xml.

It is probably a little messy here, let me know if you need anything else. I am pretty confused myself too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the property XYCtrlVisible you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged
That is how the UI is notified of a changed

Why are you binding that two way?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is an existing code, so I am trying not to change much. Care to share a little how to implement INotifyPropertyChanged? I am really new bie to WPF?

Comment: Just search msdn.microsoft.com  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx